# VS Code portable on Linux is still using for packages local user folder instead of the enviroment folder, and because of that imports fail

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I created a virtual environment with venv.

```
venv --python=/workspace/dev/python3.9 /var_path/var_virtual_env
```

In Visual Studio Code(portable version -Linux) I have set:

```
"python.venvPath": "/var_path/var_virtual_env",
"python.formatting.provider": "black"
```

The environment is seen in VSCode:

[image]

[image]

Code with python built-ins works without a problem.

From VS Code terminal with virtual environment activated using `pip` I installed different packages and I expected the packages to be imported in the virtual environment, but instead seems that they are installed in the`/home/user_name/local/lib/python3.6`.

Also I noticed that the configurations like`pylint.d` etc are at same location in "local". The pylint was set thru VSCode.

To fix it I installed the packages in the environment outside VSCode, but the editor doesn't sees them. Example `httpx`:

[image: enter code here]

But they are in the environment, pip freeze output:

[image]

How can I fix this ?

Comment: 1. Please share command by which you create virtual env. 2. Please share screenshot of bottom blue bar of vscode, when your project is opened in vscode. 3. Please share full content of ./.vscode/settings.json from your project

Comment: @KarolZlot added more info. The other things in json are related to theme and fonts, panels.

Comment: I think that answer by RobBlanchard is the solution

Comment: I have an idea: use any program to record desktop and paste here GIF from starting with creating new project and venv and showing problem. That would give better view of where is the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a terminal where the scarlette environment is activated, copy the output of `which python`.

Set in `settings.json` the following line:

```json
{
    "python.pythonPath": "paste_the_output_here"
    ....
}
```

I don't know if it will work in your case but that did the trick for me several times.

Comment: it shows me "/usr/bin/python " which is not right because this is the OS python, a smaller version

Comment: @user3541631 If `which python` returned `/usr/bin/python`, then you did not properly source your virtual environment.

Comment: @WillDaSilva is right, you have to activate your environment with `source /path/to/activate` before running `which python`.

Answer (score 1):

Click on:

[image]

And then choose python from venv.

Let know what happened.

Comment: To build on this what this will do via the gui is add .vscode/settings.json file which will contain something like this:

{
    "python.pythonPath": "sitelampy/.venv/bin/python3.8"
}

You'll still need to activate your environment, though normally when you open up a new shell (rather than the default one that vscode starts up) vscode will activate the environment for you.

Answer (score 1):

I think virtual env is ok, but you didn't activated it in console.

And also I think it will be more intuitive if you create venv relatively, in the same folder as app, then just add it to .gitignore and .dockerignore

Execute this command to create virtual environment:

```sh
python -m venv .venv --prompt ${PWD##*/}
```

Then activate:

```sh
source .venv/bin/activate
```

---

More advanced:

```sh
echo "creating virtual environment"
python -m venv .venv --prompt ${PWD##*/}

echo "upgrading pip & wheel"
.venv/bin/python -m pip install -U pip
.venv/bin/pip install wheel

echo "installing dependencies from requirements.txt"
.venv/bin/pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Then activate:

```sh
source .venv/bin/activate
```

---

(You can also activate by opening new terminal instance in vscode, or aby destroying current one and opening new)